# Error with apply function

Tags: r, spotfire, terr

I have a dtl table and a lookup table (GLMap)

dtl:

```
DEAL_TYPE   DN_DIRECTION    key COMPANY_CODE    GLAccount
POWER   SALE        1   AFFL_CO 1702
POWER   PURCHASE    2   AFFL_CO 3702
MISC    SALE        3   AFFL_CO 5717
MISC    PURCHASE    4   AFFL_CO 5718
POWER   SALE        5   AFFL_CO 1702
POWER   SALE        6   MAIN    
POWER   PURCHASE    7   MAIN    
MISC    SALE        8   MAIN    
MISC    PURCHASE    9   MAIN    
POWER   SALE        10  MAIN
```

Lookup Table (GLAcctMap):

```
DealType    DR_CR   GLAccount   Customer
POWER   P   3702    AFFL_CO
POWER   S   1702    AFFL_CO
MISC    P   5718    AFFL_CO
MISC    S   5717    AFFL_CO
POWER   P   6702    STD
POWER   S   6712    STD
MISC    P   5312    STD
MISC    S   5313    STD
```

Expected Output: 
DEAL_TYPE   DN_DIRECTION    key COMPANY_CODE    GLAccount  GLACCT
POWER   S   1   AFFL_CO 1702    1702
POWER   P   2   AFFL_CO 3702    3702
MISC    S   3   AFFL_CO 5717    5717
MISC    P   4   AFFL_CO 5718    5718
POWER   S   5   AFFL_CO 1702    1702
POWER   S   6   MAIN            6712
POWER   P   7   MAIN            6702
MISC    S   8   MAIN            5313
MISC    P   9   MAIN            5312
POWER   S   10  MAIN            6712

I would like to create an Output table which is a copy of the dtl table but with an extra GLACCT column added based on a match on multiple columns from the lookup table.

Logic is: if GLAccount column is null then go get the matching Account from the lookup table (GLacctMap), else put the GLAccount number in the new column.

Here's a function I tried:

```
load_details <- function(dld) {
```

phys_fin = 0

```
 findgl <- function(x){ 
    if( is.na(x$GLAccount)  ) {   
             GLACCT <- GLacctMap[ match( paste(x$DEAL_TYPE, x$DN_DIRECTION, sep=":"), 
                                         paste( GLacctMap$DealType,GLacctMap$DR_CR,sep=":")), "GLAccount"]    
         } else {

              GLACCT <- x$GLAccount
         }    
   GLACCT 
    }
```

dld$GLACCT <- apply(currdld, 1, function(x) findgl )

}

PEDLD <- load_details(currdld)

I get the following Error: 
IBCO Spotfire Statistics Services returned an error: 'Error in as.data.frame.default(passed.args[[i]], stringsAsFactors = s : cannot coerce class '"function"' into a data.frame'.

Comment: If you aren't using terr in spotfire can you remove the tag? Cheers.

Comment: I am running this using terr in spotfire.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what you are expecting. If you wanted a row by row application of that function and one of your columns were named "GLAccout" then you could do this:

```
temptb$GLACCT <- apply(temptb, 1, function(x) findgl( x ) )
```

Or:

```
temptb$GLACCT <- apply(temptb, 1,  findgl )
```

But it makes no sense to do a column by column application (which is what the "2" would be doing) of a function to a named column. But in order for such a strategy to succeed you need to do some testing and with some actual data I would start with this completely untested modification:

```
findgl <- function(x){ 
        if( is.na(x$GLAccount)  ) {   # no way to be length 0 or null
                 GLACCT <- GLacctMap[ match( paste( dld$COMPANY_CODE, dld$DLT_DEAL_TYPE, dld$DN_DIRECTION, sep=":"), 
                                             paste(GLacctMap$DealType,GLacctMap$DR_CR,sep=":")), "GLAccount"]    
             } else{
                GLACCT <- x$GLAccount
             }    
       GLACCT 
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  When I try to use either of the calls to the function as you suggested, I get the following error: Error in SpotfireData::exportDataToSBDF(data, file = file) : column &apos;GLACCT&apos; has inconsistent column length'.

Comment: Let me try to explain better.  I want to add a column in this table (GLACCT) based on a lookup table which has specific values for named companies, and default value for others (STD).  Yes, I want a row by row application of the function.  One of my columns in the lookup table (GLacctMap) is GLAccount.  I would like to read the value it contains for all named companies, and the default values for all the others, based on the current row's match from my base table on just the deal type and DR_CR.

Comment: If you need to explain or modify the substance of a question, the proper place to do it is  an [edit] in the body of the question. The best way to get a tested answer is to present a working example. The best way to encourage responders is to upvote useful answers.

Comment: Another error I keep getting is: 'Error in findgl(x) : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors'.

Comment: I SAY AGAIN: Edit your question to reflect all the code that produces errors and include a minimal complete example.

Comment: I have updated the question with sample data and coded.

Comment: There's no DLT_DEAL_TYPE field and that "key' in the column names made me wonder if that this in not really R but rather a commercial variant. There's also no 'GLAccount' value for half of your dtl cases. You should post the output of `dput(dtl)` and `dput(GLAcctMap)` and get all your spelling straightened out.

Comment: I have added an expected output. I am new to SO ... and trying to convey what I need. I simply want the best way to add the extra column based on a lookup. If apply is not the best way to go .. I am looking for suggestions. thanks